# TextReader class line count

Tags: c#, text, count, lines, textreader

Hello. Recently, I learned about the class `TextReader` and about how to read a text file.
However, there are some things I don't really understand.

Assuming this is a new object:

```
TextReader TR = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Text1.txt");
```

So I want to know how many letters are in there so I'm typing this, right?

```
Console.WriteLine(TR.ReadToEnd().Length);
```

However, it returns a number for the first line, it's current, but when I'm adding new lines. 
The length increases with or without anything typed.
Assuming it's the `\n` code which is a new line [maybe I'm wrong but it's making sense]

So i need to decrease the length like that:

```
current length - line count*2
```

So I get the right amount of letters in my text file.
The problem is: how do I get the number of lines?

Is there another way to check for the letter's count? If there is, how? Anyway, how do I get the number of Lines in the text file??

Thanks. =)

Comment: `it returns some number for the first line its current but when im adding new lines the length increases with or without me typing anything.`  What does that mean exactly?

Comment: it returns some numbe. for the first line its currect, but when i add new lines, the length increases with or without me typing anything. 

sorry english is not my main language :S
anyway what im trying to say is that:
if my text file has only 1 line the length property returns the currect number of letters however if it has morethen 1 lines it adds +2 to the count but there are no more letters..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since .NET framework 2.0 there is a shortcut method `ReadAllLines`:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
var count = lines.Length;
```

Comment: isnt there a way to do it with the TextReader that i mentioned? :\

Comment: @user1607836 - yes, you can run your own while-loop reading and counting lines but ReadAllLines is so much shorter.